# carrierwave thumb issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave, rmagick

This question was asked, but no answer given...I'm having the same issue.

I'm using carrierwave for uploading files everything works great until i wanted to create thumbs

images are saved in a tmp direct, but kept at the same size...

My avatar_uploader.rb file looks like this:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
include CarrierWave::RMagick
storage :file
def store_dir
   "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
end
```

My view has the following:

```
<% for image in @posts %>
<%= image_tag image.avatar_url(:thumb) if image.avatar? %>
<%= image.title %>
<% end %>
```

When I don't include (:thumb), I see the full images...but when I do include the (:thumb), I get the following error:

```
Version thumb doesn't exist!
```

below is my model setup

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comments, :frame, :title, :twitter, :avatar
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

I can see that a tmp directory was created, but images not resized...I have imagemagick and rmagick installed...

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like the version methods isn't even getting processed. Why don't you add a debugger statement (or breakpoint or puts "something") within carrierwave and see if it's working. Specifically, in carrierwave/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb and search for the version method. One thing that might be happening is that you are defining two AvatarUploaders and one of them doesn't have the thumb version.

Answer (score 9):

I think you might want to recreate versions since you might have create thumb size for some images after you uploaded some other files.

```
image.avatar.url(:thumb)
```

above syntax is fine

To recreate versions try running

```
image.avatar.recreate_versions!
```

on all avatars you might be missing.

Answer (score 4):

Try one of these syntaxes:

```
image.avatar.thumb.url
# or
image.avatar.url(:thumb)
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried both.  The first version gives the error "undefined method `thumb' for /uploads/IMG_0185.jpg:AvatarUploader".  The second version gives the error "Version thumb doesn't exist!"  Any other suggestions?   Appreciate the help.

Comment: Ok just edited my answer, let me know if that bottom part helps at all.

Comment: Also you have another `end` at the end of your AvatarUpload class, I assume, that just got cut off?

Comment: Yeah, still have the end at the bottom of the class.  Add the public, but still getting the same errors.  Just confused on why it wouldn't recognize thumb as a method when it's clearly there.

Comment: I have an almost identical setup, hmmm... could we see the model where its set up?

Comment: sure, added my model setup to my comments

Comment: typically the temp directory is just used to store the image before it gets processed, if the image is still in there and there is no 'posts' directory then your comp might be having problems processing the images

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to Use

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
```

instead of

```
include CarrierWave::RMagick
```

Because their may be case that you don't have all dependent libs of RMagick. Thumb version is created using RMagick or MiniMagick. Problem is with your RMagick.

Comment: my issue was that I had enabled / uncommented both at first, after reading your answer I just enabled mini magick but that did not work then i commented and enabled rmagick and that did it..

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the Dragon fly  Gem? I know i am not solving your problem. But after a using a couple of times i think it's better than carrierwave when it comes to images. Dragonfly gem doesn't create a lot of images just resizes one image to what ever size you specify, compared to carrierwave which creates a lot of thumbs.

Comment: Would rather stick with carrierwave for the time being...but if I really can't get this to work, will try out dragonfly instead.